# Which font is used in MS-DOS?

Tags: fonts, font-face, truetype, windows-console

Does anyone know which is the font that the Windows console/MS-DOS uses?

Comment: Not programming question. See you in superuser.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_%28typeface%29)

Comment: Consolas is the font name I see on Windows 10

Comment: Terminal was used on some versions of Windows, but modern Windows versions use TrueType fonts. My system seems to default to Courier New. 

However, the terminal in Windows is not MS-DOS. MS-DOS (and other text-mode software) uses the character data built in to the video card ROM.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct, and doesn't address the MS-DOS reference in the original question.

Answer (score 24):

The one that I grew up with in the days of VGA is called "Code page 437"

The closest one I've seen is called "More Perfect DOS VGA"

It can be downloaded here: 
http://laemeur.sdf.org/fonts/

I've only found one discrepancy so far: the ` is a little different from 437.

Comment: A "code page" is not a font. A code page is a mapping of a number to an abstract character, while a font gives the graphical representation of the character.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437 has the character-set

Comment: By now there's a page that has information about the different IBM fonts used throughout the MS-DOS era. Many font recreations on this site are mimicking fonts that were based off of code page 437. The VGA font is especially nostalgic.
https://int10h.org/oldschool-pc-fonts/fontlist/?1#ibm-g2 (link is also in the more detailed answer below by TomXP411).

Answer (score 18):

MS-DOS and the Windows terminal are two different things.

MS-DOS uses the ROM font built into your hardware: the font is actually built into a ROM chip on the video card, and it's not part of the operating system at all. Those fonts are actually a set of bitmap images, and graphics cards would actually use different bitmaps for different display modes. Your graphics card
can display that text, but only when Windows is not running.

The Windows terminal uses whatever font you pick. You can see the default font by opening a terminal (Command Prompt) and looking at the properties in the system menu (the icon in the upper-left corner of the window.)

In older versions of Windows, I believe that defaulted to a bitmap font named "Terminal", but that seems to have changed, and in the current version of Windows 10, it defaults to Courier New.

The difference is that Terminal is a raster font, and Courier New is a TrueType font. Raster fonts are actually stored as individual pixels and cannot scale to different sizes effectively. Instead, the font actually has different size versions in the font file, and the closest version is picked by the operating system when a specific size is requested. Extremely large text is not viable, and "in between" sizes must be approximated and usually look blocky and ugly.

Vector fonts (including PostScript, TrueType, and OpenType fonts) can scale to any size without losing quality. This is because the font is stored as lines and curves, rather than pixel data.

For a TrueType font that looks like the old VGA font, check out the Old School Font Pack at https://int10h.org/oldschool-pc-fonts/readme/ or http://webdraft.hu/fonts/classic-console/

I'm writing a serial/Telnet terminal program, and I use the Classic Console font above to get back to that 80s DOS look. (The program will eventually run full screen - no menus or even mouse cursor. It's going to be legit old school.)

And just for fun, you should check out the Glass VT220 font: https://github.com/lalo/VT220-mod-font

A couple of side notes, reading this article a few years later:

MS-DOS only runs on hardware or in a hypervisor. If you are running Windows NT, XP, or newer, you do not have DOS in your system at all. Windows actually has two different command processors now, cmd and PowerShell. Both are native Windows applications that provide roughly the same function as the DOS command prompt (command.com). In both cases, we'd refer to the *terminal*, rather than "MS-DOS" (any program can use the terminal; not all Windows programs have windows.)

With Windows 95, 98, and ME, running "command.com" did open a true DOS prompt, which was ran as a 16-bit process in Windows. Running the DOS prompt full screen would use the ROM fonts, and running it in a window would (I believe) use a soft font.

Also, vector fonts are also known as **outline** fonts. The terms are synonymous, but "outline" is probably a term you'll hear among typesetting professionals, while "vector" is a term you'll hear from graphic artists.

Answer (score 4):

The font used is attached [here](http://www.dafont.com/perfect-dos-vga-437.font)
Its a low px font

Comment: Thank you for the link.  Can you elaborate on if this is the exact font that is used, or one which looks very similar?

Answer (score 1):

MS-DOS properties says `Raster Fonts`. There is also one more option called `Lucida Console`. No other font is available in Windows XP

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:
[TrueType](http://webdraft.eu/fonts/classic-console/?fbclid=IwAR2JfNEUWMbJTPbiMAwm-o-l9YRxYCPosyNYyomCf4yuu9FE9BPW9GTdI-4) font

Answer (score 0):

Different version ( and locale) of MS-DOS use different font. Check it in MS-DOS Properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own font for MS DOS. It was quite simple. I made one for  my personal use that made the characters slightly larger in the "box".